# CSS transition out causing errors

Tags: css, html, transition

I have various transition effects on mouseover, such as changing image opacity. However I want a smooth transition when the mouse is moved off the item, and so I added transition code to the normal #div as well as the ##div:hover, however this is causing it to "transition" in on page  load  in a rather unsightly manner (doesn't work when refreshed, only on first instance of page load) and was wondering whether there's an equivalent to javascript's mouseout function so that the transition does not occur on page load.

Here is an example of some of the CSS:

```
#main_categories_item_image img {
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s;
    -moz-transition: all .5s;
    transition: all .5s;    
    box-shadow: #000 0em 0em 0em;
}
#main_categories_item:hover 
#main_categories_item_image img {
    opacity: 0.7;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s;
    -moz-transition: all .5s;
    transition: all .5s;
}
```

And I'm working on the website www.ultimate-punch.com

Many Thanks

Comment: Instead find what's making it stop rather than going for dirty javascript solutions for such a simple thing

Comment: It's looking fine to me on Chrome. That second selector seems like it should be more like #main_categories_item_image:hover img to be symmetrical.

Comment: Yeh it does you have to load the page from scratch (no refresh) annd watch carefully as the elements expand from nothing into the size they are declared

Comment: Why not set the transition on opacity instead of all ?

Comment: That's worked as well as I think it could - one of the elements uses width as the transition so on pageload  is still "grows", but it's only a small icon and the rest works so I'll find the solution for that later. Thanks!